# How do I password protect my webservers document root?

Tags: server, lamp, webserver

I have installed LAMP using tasksel and it is for a development system. I was wondering if I could password protect the folder /var/www/ and when someone goes to developmentservername.mydomain.com, I want it to ask for username and password.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a htaccess-file to require a password authentification. Take a look at this guide, it is really simple:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/